# A question based on Product Topology in $X \times Y$

Tags: general-topology

I am self studying Topology from Foundations of Topology  Wayne Patty and couldn't understand this argument in the theorem on page 73 ( theorem 2.16).

Adding its image:

[image]

Question: How does in second last line of proof $ U $ is a subset of $ B_d((a_1, a_2), \varepsilon) $ is derived?

Can you please give a rigorous proof? Definition of $U$ and $V$ is clear.

Comment: In the statement of the theorem it mentions the product metric $d$, so he must have defined it earlier in the textbook.

Comment: Once you find the definition of product metric it should be a simple verification. Based on the given proof, I think the product metric is $d = \sqrt{d_1^2 + d_2^2}$, you should be able to verify the inclusion with that.